# Laravel eloquent filter from a value of json column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've taken over a project where they stored the `date_start` value in a JSON column.

**(e.g, id, name, some_column, meta)**
where in **meta** has a value of `{ propert1, property2, property3, "date_start": "2021-09-26", and so on...}`

Now, in the front-end, I have to make a search feature, where I select a date.

Now in the back-end, since the value of `date_start` has been stored in a json column, I'd assume that I need to fetch all records first, loop through them and then decode the `meta` field.

Isn't it OVERALL bad? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern versions of database often support JSON column types. These json columns can be queried using SQL.

`preferences` column in `users` table:

```json
{"dining": {"meal": "salad", "time": "20:00"}}
```

Query:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('preferences->dining->meal', 'salad')
                ->get();
```

Checkout the Laravel docs on [JSON Where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses):